# Статическая ссылка на нестатический внутренний класс

Tags: java, классы, inner

**Вот отрывок кода**

```
public class A {
    static B b = new B(); //'A.this' cannot be referenced from a static context
    static C c = new C();

    public class B {
    }
}

class C {

}
```

Вопрос в следующем: Почему компилятор ругается на вторую строчку коду? Пытаюсь разобраться и понять в чём проблема, но ничего не лезет в голову. Объясните, кто может несчастному ламеру, пожалуйста.
Знаю, что такое static. В принципе понимаю, почему внутренний класс так связан с внешним, если не ошибаюсь, то дело в неявном добавлении в конструктор внутреннего класса ссылки на объект внешнего класса. Поправьте, если что-то не то. В этой теме(с внутренними классами) я совсем глуп

Comment: "В принципе понимаю, почему ... в неявном добавлении ... на объект внешнего класса" - что, собственно, еще здесь нужно?

Comment: Не совсем понял к чему вы клоните. Если вам не составит труда, ответьте, как вы понимаете эту ситуацию.

Comment: Я понимаю эту ситуацию так, как Вы и написали. Создание объекта нестатического вложенного класса имеет смысл (допустимо) в контексте объекта класса-контейнера. Для статического поля объекта класса-контейнера нет - это вызывает ошибку компиляции.

Comment: Поставьте `static` перед `public class B {` или уберите `static` перед `B b = new B();`.

Comment: Очень сложно для понимания. Как решить проблему знаю, но мне интересен сам механизм препятствующий такой реализации. На днях увидел код, в котором была подобная проблема, но её решили другим способом. Создали экземпляр класса в методе, но оставили также ссылочную переменную статической и вложенный класс также нестатический. И вот просто голова взрывается, когда пытаюсь понять этот момент

Comment: "но её решили другим способом" - это неправильное решение. Что Вам непонятно в моем объяснении? Ответ "взрывается голова" не принимается.

Comment: Так мне вот в принципе и непонятно, почему именно класс-контейнер. Прошу простить за навязчивость и за долгие ответы, стараюсь каждое слово Ваше обдумать

Comment: "почему именно класс-контейнер" - класс-контейнер что? Пишите, пожалуйста, вопросы полностью.

Comment: А-а, кажется понял. Объект внутреннего класса не может существовать без внешнего. static модификатор свидетельствует о том, что значение его может быть доступно, уже при загрузке самого класса посредством JVM (A). Но так как в моем случае, не создавая объект внешнего класса, я пытаюсь инициализировать ссылку объектом внутреннего класса, это и приводит к ошибке.

Comment: *"Объект внутреннего класса не может существовать без внешнего."* Точка.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема в том что любой созданный вами объект  внутреннего не статического класса (B) должен создаваться с ссылкой на внешний объект класса (A). Поэтому, объекты класса B должны иметь возможность идентифицировать объект класса A который и привел к их созданию.

А как тогда тут у вас определить к какому объекту класса A должен быть связан объект класса B если вы его создаете как static поле, которое как мы знаем относится ко всему классу A в целом, соответственно в вашем случае получается что для всех объектов A соответствует единый объект B. Из-за этого по своей природе внутренний класс не может иметь такого поведения. Поэтому либо уберите static в месте объявления поля, либо сделайте B static классом и тогда он не будет нуждаться в связке с объектом класса A, ибо такой объект уже не имеет доступа к состоянию конкретного объекта класса A и существует как самостоятельный.

Если вы так в этом не уверенны то попробуйте создать объект внутреннего класса B в static методе класса A. Вам выдаст ту самую ошибку.

Если чего то не понятно задавайте вопросы, попытаюсь лучше объяснить и так пытался как можно короче. ( Извиняюсь за отсутствие форматирования, пишу ответ с телефона ).

Comment: Я поэкспериментировал и получил ответ чуть ранее вашего, но всё равно благодарю! Знаний мало не бывает! Учту всё Ваше. Как я понял, моя проблема заключалась в том, что я пытался инициализировать статическую ссылку объектом внутреннего класса. А как известно, что все статические поля и методы становятся доступны на этапе *инициализации* самого класса средствами JVM, отсюда следует, что я пытаюсь создать объект внутреннего класса, при этом не имея соответствующую ссылку на объект внешнего класса. Ещё раз спасибо, за развёрнутый ответ!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйсто